# How to get HTML% Radio button value in C#?

Tags: c#, html, radio-button

I want to get the selected radio button value in C#.
I used the following code for radio button.

```
<input id="C" type="radio" name ="language" value ="C" /> <label for = "C">C</label> <br>
<input id="C++" type="radio" name ="language" value ="C++" /> <label for = "C++">C++</label> <br>
<input id="C#" type="radio" name ="language" value ="C#" /> <label for = "C#">C#</label> <br>
<input id="VB" type="radio" name ="language" value ="VB" /> <label for = "VB">VB</label> <br>
```

Now i want to get the selected radio button value in C#.

Comment: I would stick to [normal characters for your `id` attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/).

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form("language") should work

Comment: In your code behind, page load event, after check of existence

Answer (score 0):

Try this…

```
if (Request.Form["language"] != null)
{
     string value = Request.Form["language"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Note that Request.Form["language"] will be null if non of the RadioButtons are selected.